# PhoneAuthentication.SenderProvidedNumbers always null in DocuSign IdCheckConfigurationName == "Phone Auth $"

Tags: docusignapi

I have created an envelope with signers and setting PhoneAuthentication this way

signer.IdCheckConfigurationName = "Phone Auth $";
RecipientPhoneAuthentication phoneAuthentication = new RecipientPhoneAuthentication
{
RecipMayProvideNumber = "true",
SenderProvidedNumbers = new List()
};
phoneAuthentication.SenderProvidedNumbers.Add(signerDto.SignerCountryCode + signerDto.SignerPhoneNumber);
signer.PhoneAuthentication = phoneAuthentication;
signer.RequireIdLookup = signerDto.RequireIdLookup ? "true" : "false";`

But when I am fetching ListRecipients - Signers- IdCheckConfigurationName == "Phone Auth $"  PhoneAuthentication always null

Can you suggest why it is null?

Comment: Did you create a new developer account recently? this code above is the old phone auth code, and it will not work if you have newer accounts. You will need to use the new method

Comment: Yes, I have created developer account in Nov 2021, Can you share new phone auth code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so you are using the old way and you need to change to the new way.
You can find a [detailed article on this topic](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/phone-auth/) on developer center.
Looks like you are using C#, the C# code looks like this:

```
string workflowId = phoneAuthWorkflow.WorkflowId;

EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition()
{
    EnvelopeIdStamping = "true",
    EmailSubject = "Please Sign",
    EmailBlurb = "Sample text for email body",
    Status = "Sent"
};

byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(docPdf);

// Add a document
Document doc1 = new Document()
{
    DocumentId = "1",
    FileExtension = "pdf",
    Name = "Lorem",
    DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
};

// Create your signature tab
env.Documents = new List<Document> { doc1 };
SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
{
    AnchorString = "/sn1/",
    AnchorUnits = "pixels",
    AnchorXOffset = "10",
    AnchorYOffset = "20"
};

// Tabs are set per recipient/signer
Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
{
    SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 }
};


string workflowId = workflowId;

RecipientIdentityVerification workflow = new RecipientIdentityVerification()
{
    WorkflowId = workflowId,
    InputOptions = new List<RecipientIdentityInputOption> {
        new RecipientIdentityInputOption
        {
Name = "phone_number_list",
ValueType = "PhoneNumberList",
PhoneNumberList = new List<RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber>
{
    new RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber
    {
        Number = phoneNumber,
        CountryCode = countryAreaCode,
    }
}
        }
    }
};

Signer signer1 = new Signer()
{
    Name = signerName,
    Email = signerEmail,
    RoutingOrder = "1",
    Status = "Created",
    DeliveryMethod = "Email",
    RecipientId = "1", //represents your {RECIPIENT_ID},
    Tabs = signer1Tabs,
    IdentityVerification = workflow,
};

Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
recipients.Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 };
env.Recipients = recipients;
```

Comment: When I am trying to find IdentityVerification using this code, count is always 0. Do I need to make any change in setting or Do I need to contact DocuSign Account Manager or Partner Account Manager for the same?

Comment: Your account may not have it enabled. If you create a new developer account - it will have it automatically, so that's a quick way to test this, but to get it into your existing account - you'll have to contact DocuSign support.

Comment: Identity Verification/ Phone Authenticatio is coming in developer account (https://admindemo.docusign.com/identity-verification), but when it is in Production (https://admin.docusign.com/sending-settings) environment it is not showing, how it will be visible?

Comment: You will need to contact customer support with your production account information so they can add it for you.